# Links contains #, would it affect SEO?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, seo, mvcsitemapprovider

If i have such links in my site (i am using mvcsitemap):

```
http://mysite.com/coollink
http://mysite.com/coollink#contanttab1
http://mysite.com/coollink#contenttab2
```

If i want to submit site map to google for example, should i use the links with # in mysite XML sitemap? or better not to use them in sitemap XML?

Because in such case there would be 3 links to the same resource as i understand and it is not so good for SEO? could some one correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/768233/413670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know so far, hashes will be ignored by most of the search engines and they have no use for SEO. It is user more for internal page navigation or some sort of JavaScript actions.